# Extract Prismic Obj from response to Angular 13 View as HTML

Tags: angular, api, prismic.io

I've been looking at responses on this topic, and I'm having a hard time handling the response from a http call to the prismic api.  I can get a response from the api, however,I'm have a hell of a time extracting. I'm newer Angular and Prismic, but apparently I do have the understanding of JS http responses that I thought

I want to extract from the response an update put them in HTML
so   document.getElementByTag("div").innerHTML = {response.property};...

Thank you for any feedback!

**Model**

```
    export class Post {
    page: number
    results_per_page: number
    results_size: 2
    total_results_size: number
    total_pages: number
    next_page: number
    prev_page: number
    results: Result
    version: number
    license: string
  }

  export class Result{
 
       id: string ;
       uid: number ;
       url: number ;
       type: number ;
       href: number ;
       tags: [] ;
       first_publication_date: number ;
       last_publication_date: number ;
       slugs: [] ;
       linked_documents: number ;
       lang: number ;
       alternate_languages: [ ];
       data: {}


 }
```

**View**

```
    <div class="container">

    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{nav_name}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div class="container" *ngFor=" let post of posts">
  <div class="card" *ngFor=" let d in post.results"  >
    <div class="card-title">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
  </div>
    <div>{{ d | json}}</div>
    <div>{{post | json}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Servivce**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Post } from './nav/post';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {

  fakeUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
  fakeUrl_2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  prismic = "https://myPrismicRepo.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2/documents/search?ref=Y..."

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getPosts(): Observable<any>{
    
  //  return this.http.get<{[key: string]: Post}>(this.prismic)
  return this.http.get(this.prismic)
}
}


**Component** 

    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TitleStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ConfigService } from '../config.service';
import { Post, Result} from './post';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css'],
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  nav_name = 'myShop';
  posts: Post[]=[];
  myData: Result[] =[];
  loading: Boolean =false;
  errorMessage;
  token="my prismic token"
  query ="&q=%5B%5B%3Ad+%3D+at%28document.id%2C+%22Yt3JQhAAACIAKlc3%22%29+%5D%5D"
  
  fakeUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
  fakeUrl_2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  prismic ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {

  
  }
   getPosts(){
    const postArray :Post[] = [];
       this.configService.getPosts()
       .pipe(
      //    map((responseData) =>{
      //    for(const key in responseData){
      //      //check for other key properties
      //      if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      //      postArray.push({...responseData[key], id: key})
      //     }
      //    }
      //    return postArray;
      //  })
      map( (response: Post) =>
         
      response.results[1].filter((x: Result) => x.id === "Yt3JQhAAACIAKlc3" )
         
      )
       )
       .subscribe((response) => {
         console.log(response);
        //  this.posts = response ;

       }, (error)=> {
        this.errorMessage = error;
           console.log(this.errorMessage );
          
           
           this.loading = false;
       }
       );
   }


  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPosts();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend putting your code into a StackBlitz Environment where your code can be inspected in a working environment. People can fork it, fix it and repost the solution here for other to benefit. Here's the link for StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/?starters=frontend

Comment: thank you ,  Please the stackblitz hrere

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/TicoGitHubII/myShop?file=src/app/nav/post.ts

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this was easy -- so to speak. Probably the reason for not many responses. But for rusty and novice devs this will help. I just went  to the most *simple Angular Http request* format using the Observeable type to hold the response and for there it just digging into the array response one step and at a time. Each time creating the model interface that I needed and passing the view and
using the *ngFor directive to interate over the update response model .

```
 getPosts(): Observable<any>{
    
  return this.http.get(this.prismic)
 
}
}

  getPosts() {

this.configService
  .getPosts()
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      let data = response['results'];
      this.myData.push(...data);
      let header =  response['results'][0].data.header;
      this.myPSHeader.push({...header}).toString;

      console.log(response);
      console.log( this.myData )
      
    },
    (error) => {
      this.errorMessage = error;
      console.log(this.errorMessage);

      this.loading = false;
    }
  );
```

}

As for the prismic helper packages, after all the long toiling , I dug deep into prismic community and found a demo for Angular and Prismic.
So I hope this helps someone. Thanks Prismic team  _ ! [Prismic Community](https://community.prismic.io/t/cant-preview-prismic-page-in-my-angular-application/868)